# Firestore checking if a document exist in collection

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to make a code for uploading item/stock to firestore. what i want is if the Item is already registered in firestore, then recalculate the quantity. But if the item is not registered yet in firestore, system add new document to firestore.

I already make a code like below, if i try to add item that is already registered it succeed on recalculating the quantity but the problem is when i want to add new item ( that is not registered in database) it doesnt work. Can somebody fix my code.

```
final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        merk = etMerk.getText().toString().trim();
        type = etType.getText().toString().trim();
        typemerk = type + " - " + merk;
        qty = etQty.getText().toString().trim();
        price = etPrice.getText().toString().trim();
        date = datetime.getText().toString();

        final Map<String, Object> stock = new HashMap<>();
        stock.put("date", date);
        stock.put("type", typemerk);
        stock.put("qty", qty);
        stock.put("price", price);
        stock.put("merk", merk);


        final FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        final CollectionReference documentReference = rootRef.collection("watchlist");
        Query query = documentReference.whereEqualTo("type", typemerk);
        query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        Log.d(Tag.ITEM, document.getId() + "=>" + document.getData());

                        String id = document.getString("id");
                        String oldqty = document.getString("qty");
                        Integer i = Integer.parseInt(oldqty) + Integer.parseInt(qty);
                        String newQty = String.valueOf(i);

                        Map<Object, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                        map.put("qty", newQty);
                        rootRef.collection("watchlist").document(document.getId()).set(map, SetOptions.merge());
                        Toast.makeText(AddItemActivity.this, "Berhasil menambah stok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(Tag.ITEM, "not register in DB", task.getException());
                    Toast.makeText(AddItemActivity.this, "new item to database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    documentReference
                            .add(stock)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                                    Toast.makeText(AddItemActivity.this, "Berhasil Memasukkan Barang ke Stok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    etMerk.setText("");
                                    etType.setText("");
                                    etQty.setText("");
                                    etPrice.setText("");
                                    etMerk.setFocusable(true);
                                }
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(AddItemActivity.this, "Gagal Memasukkan stok, silahkan coba lagi.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check to make sure that your query returned successfully and that it's not empty. It can return an empty result if the query was processed but there was no matching result.

```
 FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    db.collection("myCollection")
            .whereEqualTo("myQuery", myQueryValue)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

                    boolean documentExists;

                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Log.d("QueryResult", "Is query result empty: " + task.getResult().isEmpty());
                        documentExists = !task.getResult().isEmpty();

                    }else{
                        Log.e("QueryResult", "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                        documentExists = false;
                    }

                    if(documentExists){
                        Log.d("QueryResult", "The document exists");
                        // Do whatever you need to do with the document
                    }else{
                        Log.d("QueryResult", "The document doesn't exist or there was an error retrieving it");
                        // Create the document or whatever else you need to do
                    }
                }
            });
```